# Google Sheet array formula

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I've a problem with google sheet i have a couple of article with an id, a price and then a list of article buyed. I represented the list of articles buyed by numbers separated with commas.

I know how to find the price of an article by it's id i put it in the sheet. Now i need to know how i can get the total of the articles buyed but i don't find the solution.

Can you help me please ?

[Link to view the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L55rXMaYJGBMMgpCMH2kwpq_j0QKSdwL2VxJjiZsv1w/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In E2 try

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(iferror(vlookup(split(D2:D8; ","); A2:B8; 2; 0); 0); {1;1;1}))
```

Is this what you try to achieve?

[image]

Comment: It dosent works on my sheet, do you have an example of it's implementation ? I need to have in column E the sum of each product price tagged in D

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. I updated the answer... see if that is what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Yes i don't understand why it doesn't worker earlier when i post my comment

Answer (score 0):

This a job for an [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en)

```
=HLOOKUP(F2;$A$2:$B$8;2;FALSE)
```

This can be read

> Look up, based on the key in F2, the row in the range A2:B8, and take the 2nd column. Don't rely on the keys being sorted

Comment: I don't understand how it works. How i can integrate in in the column E to have the sum of each product tagged the columns D